# How to change CSS value in Angular 15+ when checkbox is checked?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I want to change the height of the vertical timeline when a specific checkbox is checked.
For example in CSS Component the height % should be changed when a checkbox is checked

```
.timeline:before {
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  position: absolute;
  content: " ";
  width: 10px;
  height:100%;
  background-color: #ccc;
  transition: all 0.3s;
  left: 49.7%;
  margin-left: -1.5px; 
}
```

This is my HTML component code

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="page-header">
        <h1 id="timeline">Timeline</h1>
        <ul>
          <li><input type="checkbox">height 8%</li>
          <li><input type="checkbox">height 25%</li>
          <li><input type="checkbox">height 38%</li>
          <li><input type="checkbox">height 53%</li>
          <li><input type="checkbox">height 72%</li>
          <li><input type="checkbox">height 100%</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <ul class="timeline">
        <li>
          <div class="timeline-badge"><button><i class="fa fa-times"></i></button></div>
          <div class="timeline-panel">
            <p>Sponsor Approval</p>
          </div>
        </li>
        <li class="timeline-inverted">
          <div class="timeline-badge"><button><i class="fa fa-times"></i></button></div>
          <div class="timeline-panel">
            <p>Initial Payment</p>
          </div>
        </li>
        <li>
          <div class="timeline-badge"><button><i class="fa fa-times"></i></button></div>
            <div class="timeline-panel">
            <p>HR Approved Date</p> 
            </div>
        </li>
        <li class="timeline-inverted">
            <div class="timeline-badge"><button><i class="fa fa-times"></i></button></div>
            <div class="timeline-panel">
            <p>Manager Approved Date</p>
            </div>
        </li>
        <li>
          <div class="timeline-badge"><button><i class="fa fa-times"></i></button></div>
            <div class="timeline-panel">
            <p>Letter of intent</p> 
            </div>
        </li>
        <li class="timeline-inverted">
          <div class="timeline-badge"><button><i class="fa fa-times"></i></button></div>
          <div class="timeline-panel">
          <p>Final Offer Leter</p>
          </div>
        </li>
    </ul>
```

This is my CSS component code

```
h1{
    text-align: center;
}
.timeline {
    list-style: none;
    padding: 20px 0 20px;
    position: relative;
}
button{
    border: none;
    background-color: transparent;
}
p{
    text-align: center;
}
.timeline:before {
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  position: absolute;
  content: " ";
  width: 10px;
  height:100%;
  background-color: #ccc;
  transition: all 0.3s;
  left: 49.7%;
  margin-left: -1.5px; 
}
.h8{
  height: 8%;
}


.timeline > li {
  margin-bottom: 2cm;
  position: relative;
}

.timeline > li:before,
.timeline > li:after {
  content: " ";
  display: table;
}

.timeline > li:after {
  clear: both;
}

.timeline > li:before,
.timeline > li:after {
  content: " ";
  display: table;
}

.timeline > li:after {
  clear: both;
}

.timeline > li > .timeline-panel {
  width: 46%;
  height: 2cm;
  float: left;
  border: 1px solid #d4d4d4;
  border-radius: 25px;
  padding: 20px;
  position: relative;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.175);
  box-shadow: 0 1px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.175);
}

.timeline > li > .timeline-panel:before {
  position: absolute;
  top: 26px;
  right: -15px;
  display: inline-block;
  border-top: 15px solid transparent;
  border-left: 15px solid #ccc;
  border-right: 0 solid #ccc;
  border-bottom: 15px solid transparent;
  content: " ";
}

.timeline > li > .timeline-panel:after {
  position: absolute;
  top: 27px;
  right: -14px;
  display: inline-block;
  border-top: 14px solid transparent;
  border-left: 14px solid #fff;
  border-right: 0 solid #fff;
  border-bottom: 14px solid transparent;
  content: " ";
}

.timeline > li > .timeline-badge {
  color: #fff;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  line-height: 50px;
  font-size: 1.4em;
  text-align: center;
  position: absolute;
  top: 16px;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -25px;
  background-color: #999999;
  z-index: 100;
  border-top-right-radius: 50%;
  border-top-left-radius: 50%;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 50%;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 50%;
}

.timeline > li.timeline-inverted > .timeline-panel {
  float: right;
}

.timeline > li.timeline-inverted > .timeline-panel:before {
  border-left-width: 0;
  border-right-width: 15px;
  left: -15px;
  right: auto;
}

.timeline > li.timeline-inverted > .timeline-panel:after {
  border-left-width: 0;
  border-right-width: 14px;
  left: -14px;
  right: auto;
}



.timeline-title {
    margin-top: 0;
    color: inherit;
}

.timeline-body > p,
.timeline-body > ul {
    margin-bottom: 0;
}

.timeline-body > p + p {
  margin-top: 5px;
}

@media (max-width: 767px) {
  ul.timeline:before {
    left: 40px;
  }

    ul.timeline > li > .timeline-panel {
        width: calc(100% - 90px);
        width: -moz-calc(100% - 90px);
        width: -webkit-calc(100% - 90px);
    }

    ul.timeline > li > .timeline-badge {
        left: 15px;
        margin-left: 0;
        top: 16px;
    }

    ul.timeline > li > .timeline-panel {
        float: right;
    }

        ul.timeline > li > .timeline-panel:before {
          
            border-left-width: 0;
            border-right-width: 15px;
            left: -15px;
            right: auto;
        }

        ul.timeline > li > .timeline-panel:after {
            border-left-width: 0;
            border-right-width: 14px;
            left: -14px;
            right: auto;
        }
}
```

Comment: What should happen if there are checkboxes skipped, i.e. only the first and last checkboxes are checked? You have added a JavaScript tag, so I assume you are looking for a JavaScript solution. What have you tried already?

Comment: I would suggest you to read the [documentation of input type checkbox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/checkbox).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I understand it, a `checkbox` is not the right tool for this job. A `checkbox` is typically used, when you **can select multiple elements**. This does not seem to be the case here. You would want the height of your timeline to be **either** 8% **or** 100% but not both at the same time, right? A `select` or group of `radio-buttons` should be used.
Then you would need an array of the selectable heights, and the currently selected height in your component:

```
public selectedHeight;
public timelineHeights = ['8%', '25%', '38%', '53%', '72%', '100%'];
```

Within your template you simple iterate over that array and create a select option for each. You also need to bind the `selectedHeight` to this select element, in order to reference its current value:

```
<select [(ngModel)]='selectedHeight'>
    <option *ngFor="let height of timelineHeights" [value]="height">height {{height}}</option>
</select>
```

Lastly you can now control your timeline height element with the `selectedHeight`:

```
<div [style]="'height:' + selectedHeight"> TIMELINE </div>
```

There is one main advantage to this approach: You will only need to change the arrays values in order to be able to control the selectable heights. These values could now even come from a service, getting them from e.g. a database or config file.

Comment: Good approach but height in % is not working in any case it is working fine only in px and cm.
Ty for your solution it helps a lot /.